# protractor test my app,Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jvm, protractor

When i run protractor test my app. Webdriver-manager stoped.

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

how can I config java Xmx with conf.js?

conf.js

```
localSeleniumStandaloneOpts:{
    jvmArgs:['-Xmx=1024m']
}
```

I do this in my conf.js  but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **replacing** **1024m** with **2048m**. 
Increasing heap memory. If it's gives you issue with 2048m you can decrease it by 1536m.

Comment: I don't know if it had worked.

maybe conf.js > jvmArgs:['-Xmx1024m'] ? needn't "-"?